# How to add "About" action to app on OS X?

Tags: macos, qt, cross-platform, desktop-application, about-box

In almost every application on OS X, if you click on the name of application, one of the actions is "About". I understand how I can do this in `QMenuBar`, but seems like it is not a part of it.

The second question is how this will be shown on Windows?

I don't use QML - how to do this in code?
Like this way:

```
QMenu *fileMenu = menuBar->addMenu("File");

QAction *newFile = new QAction("New", fileMenu);
QAction *openProjectAction = new QAction("Open project", fileMenu);
```

So how I add "About" action to group of actions of application?
Screenshot added[image: Google Chrome about]

Comment: Do you know how to add a new action in general to a menubar?

Comment: @Hayt Yes, but there is no such thing as QMenu("My name project"). If it was like Help->About, I'd already done it.      QMenu *fileMenu = menuBar->addMenu("File");

        QAction *newFile = new QAction("New", fileMenu);
        QAction *openProjectAction = new QAction("Open project", fileMenu); As proof :)

Comment: You should maybe clarify this in your question, that you want to know how to get the name of your project?

Comment: You can get/set the application name in the application itself: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop

Comment: @Hayt How this might help? In QMenuBar no such thing as getMenu

Comment: @htzfun Actually, try `Help -> About`. OS X should automatically move this action to the needed section as in your screenshot.

Comment: @kefir500 Thanks a lot - I haven't tried this one because it doesn't seem logical to me - but it worked. Could you make it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add your action as `Help --> About`.

- On **macOS** the action will be *automatically* moved to the needed section, as on your screenshot.
- On **Windows** this action will remain as is (in the `Help` section).

You may also want to take a look at the [macOS QAction roles](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#MenuRole-enum).